# Reciprocal of shifted lognormal random variable

Tags: distributions, lognormal-distribution

Let $ln(X)\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $c$ be a constant such that $X+c$ follows a shifted lognormal distribution with parameters $\mu$, $\sigma^2$, and $c$.  What I would like to know is the distribution of $\frac{1}{X+c}$.  I know that in the special case where $c=0$, $\frac{1}{X}\sim lognormal(-\mu,\sigma^2)$, but what about the more general case?

Answer (score 2):

If $Y = 1/(X+c)$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$, and $X \sim \text{Lognormal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then
$$
f_Y(y) = f_X(1/y-c)|y^{-2}|.
$$
If you're looking for the name of the distribution, I can't help you there. You can see it isn't another lognormal random variable, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can relate this to [Johnson's $S_B$-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_SU-distribution#Johnson's_SB-distribution)

$$z = \gamma + \delta \log \left(\frac{x-\xi}{\xi+\lambda-x} \right)$$

- with $\xi = 0$, $\lambda = 1/c$

  from which follows with some rearrancements

  $$\frac{z-\gamma}{\delta}= y = \log \left(\frac{cx}{1-cx} \right) \sim N(-\frac{\gamma}{\delta}, \frac{1}{\delta^2})$$
- and with $\delta = 1/\sigma$ and $\gamma = \frac{\mu-\ln(c)}{\sigma}$

$$x = \frac{1}{c+e^{-y+\ln(c)}} = \frac{1}{c+e^{y^\prime}}\\
\text{with} \quad y^\prime = \ln(c)-y \sim N\left(\mu=\ln(c)+\frac{\gamma}{\delta},\sigma^2= \frac{1}{\delta^2}\right)$$

You could also see it as a scaled [logit-/logistic-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution)